# Restore object classes on back button in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

1. I have a form. Initially an input element has the class "unfilled". As the form is filled out I dynamically remove the class.
2. The form is submitted and there is a redirect to another page.
3. I click the "back" button and come back to the original form, but the element is missing the "unfilled" class.

This not a problem in IE8.
I tried adding this jQuery call, but it is not executed when the page is reached via back button:

```
$('#my_input').hasClass('unfilled')
```

Thanks!

edit: Posted the wrong line of code above, sorry. Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_input').addClass('unfilled')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox maintains something called a bfcache ([read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching)), that basically caches the entire state of the page in memory and restores it when you go back. `onload` scripts are not executed again and elements stay in the same state they were in before. You can disable this behaviour by adding a dummy `onunload` handler to your page.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox preserves state when you go back, which is very handy on DHTML-heavy pages (if you generated a dialog for instance, that dialog will still be there when you go back).  You'll just have to account for this in your code; for instance, you could try adding an onready handler that adds an "unfilled" class to all input elements, eg.

```
$(function() {
    $("INPUT").addClass("unfilled");
 });
```